# Error when running bundle exec rake in macOS M1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, apple-m1

I installed all my gems using Rosetta, because I'm working with an old repository, but I can't run `bundle exec rake db:create` due to this error:

```
rails aborted! LoadError: dlopen(/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 0x0009): 
tried: '/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - 
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
```

I'm using a mac M1 with Monterey 12.3

I tried installing nokogiri with these options:

`gem install nokogiri -v '1.12.5' -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir=$(brow --prefix libiconv) --with-xml2-include=$(brow --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2`

`gem install nokogiri -v '1.12.5' --user-install --platform arm64-darwin`

without any luck.

Versions

- Ruby: 2.6.5
- Bundler: 1.17.3
- Nokogiri: 1.12.5

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you find the answer? i am having the same issue

Comment: @AnaMaríaGonzález Sorry for the delay. Yes, I updated the command line tools for Xcode, and the installing the gem again:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1801#issuecomment-434150397